# Codename one: How to upload app on appstore

Tags: codenameone

I want to upload app on appstore which built using codename one.
I have gone through below link 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html

If we follow above link its having dependency like MAC OS and XCode.
I dont have MAC OS to upload app.

Is there any other way to upload app on appstore without using MAC OS or Xcode?

Is there any Codename one plugin available to upload app on appstore in IOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is NO. Apple is so strict with their App submission and you can't submit an iOS or Mac app without a Mac involved.

You can use rent a Mac through [MacInCloud](https://www.macincloud.com/) to upload your `.ipa` file through **Application Loader** and finish off the submission on a normal browser.

Another virtual mac you could use is https://www.wenz.io/ApplicationLoader. They have an Application Loader ready to be used and their price is reasonable.

Comment: FYI we will probably also offer an application loader at a later date. There is some logistics involved and it's hard to fit into our task pipeline.

Comment: did you guys do this yet ?